# flutter/ how can I make motion detect with camera?

Tags: flutter, camera, detect, motion, vision

hello now I am making home training app via flutter

I wanna try to use some sensor or camera for detecting people actually move

is there have any article or package to get a clue for this one?

cuz I am not a native English speaker so hard to find some keyword for what I want

any suggestion I would really appreciate

Comment: You may have to write you own platfom-specific code to access the camera and process the image.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, motion detection in Flutter is possible using the [motion_sensors](https://pub.dev/packages/motion_sensors) plugin.

> Flutter plugin for accessing the Android and iOS accelerometer,
> gyroscope, magnetometer and orientation sensors.

You can also try the [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) package as which offers the same function as the latter.